# iphone App screen getting stuck on iOS 5

Tags: ios5

I am working on iphone application, my app is working on xcode 4.0 and later versions but when I try to test my app on xcode 4.2-iOS 5, app screen stuck inconsistently and cannot debug.

Answer (score 0):

Place breakpoints in your App delegate and in view controller's viewWillAppear that you add to window.Look at stack trace.

Comment: i did it. breakpoints working, but unable to find where aap screen get stuck.